# OverMapView is not working with sliding menu

Tags: java, android, overlay, android-mapview, slidingmenu

I have a View which have 3 items.
   + TopBarView.
   + MapView
   + ListView
In TopBarView have button left menu. Its using a slide menu like facebook app.
but my problem is when I set overlay map view and click on that button, my view have transfer and left menu available but my view jumps to old position and overlaps left menu view.

When I turn off add overlay map view then sliding menu is working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution for this. I have replaced return true by return false in Draw then its working...!